# Using webpack as build tool for React npm package

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, build

I've been playing around with **webpack** and **npm** registry. I created my [own little project.](https://github.com/Tomekmularczyk/react-did-catch) which I published to **npm** registry. Everything seems to work fine, but there is one thing that worries me.

The file which is built by webpack (`lib/index.js`) contains almost 2k lines of code while my library is really tiny. I see that it includes two dependencies that I use which are `prop-types` and `detect-browser`. They make most of the code. 
Hover after downloading these two libraries and using them in a test project I would expect them to be somehow deduped by tree-shaking or something like that, but the size of my package is still the same.

Basically, all I'm asking is: does my library includes more code than necessary? It seems like so to me.

[image]

I also tried to additionally install `prop-types` and `detect-browser` in the test project to see if bundle size will remain the same. Hower the size of my library is still the same and bundle size increased (I expected that redundant libraries will be removed or something).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How did you generate the dependency graph?

BTW your package looks fine except for the fact that your are including in you distributed code both the packages you are depending on (`prop-types` and `detect-browser`).

In order to avoid that you should mark as `external` those libraries in your webpack config file. Like:

```
externals: {
    react: 'react',
    prop-types: 'prop-types',
    detect-browser: 'detect-browser',
}
```

Just a final (personal) note: give [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/) a try to bundle your libraries. :)

Comment: I used webpack-bundle-analyzer for dependency graph. Why libraries like `react-bootstrap` have only `react` and `react-dom` marked as externals? ReactBootstrap is also using `prop-types` and other libraries as their dependencies. Btw, your snippet is invalid ;)

Comment: react-bootstrap has a quite complex [build setup](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/tree/master/tools). I don't know what's happening in there!